# Single word for someone who speaks confidently, potentially falsely without data, backup or despite counter evidence

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm searching for an adjective to describe someone who emphatically makes claims without sufficient knowledge or factual basis. Someone who essentially sounds like or plays the expert, without the expertise. Could be a noun as well maybe?

- EX: I can't help but question his statements, despite his (conclusive) bravado.
- EX: I can't help but question his statements, he is a (blank)
- EX: I can't help but question his statements, he is by reputation (inarguable).

I thought of these not sure...

- assertive
- indisputable
- unarguable
- conclusive
- vehement

Comment: #1 and #2 seem to be looking for opposite words or phrases.

Comment: "Bloviate" is informal, but it implies a skepticism about the usefulness of the speaker's output (or bloviation).

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  Who is speaking in your examples, the bloviator or the unbiased critic?

Comment: One common phrase that you could use if you were quite sure that the person actually knows nothing about the subject is that they are "full of it".   "it" may also be replaced with "hot air", "crap", "bull" etc.  But this doesn't really fit with your examples at all.

Comment: Demagogue. Rabble-rouser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the word **ultracrepidarian**.

> **someone who has no special knowledge of a subject but who expresses an opinion about it**
>
> > "I avoid commenting on football for fear of being called an ultracrepidarian."

You can find this word in following on-line dictionaries: [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/polite-words-for-impolite-people/ultracrepidarian), [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ultracrepidarian), and [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/ultracrepidarian).

You may also want to consider the word **sophist.**

> **A person who reasons with clever but false arguments.**
>
> > "Some Sophists never mind taking help of *ipse dixit*."

Link to this word on [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sophist) and [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sophist)

Comment: A typical sophist, unlike the kind of person that the OP has in mind, has a great deal of knowledge of the subject matter he is talking about; it is that knowledge that enables him to deliberately and cleverly make misleading arguments.

Comment: *Ultracrepidarian* may be, in some way, an apt word to use for such a person, but is unlikely to facilitate the comprehension of whatever point one is trying to make about that person. Its use may be somewhat amusing, but only to those who are familiar with the Latin proverb on which it is based.

Comment: @jsw29 The meaning of Sophist that you are referring to is the etymological in nature. Whereas, I disagree to your assertion about the word Ultracrepidarian. Or better, if you can provide your insight on the word Ultracrepidarian and enlighten us.

Comment: The word *ultracrepidarian* embodies an allusion to the saying 'ne sutor ultra crepidam', which means 'let a sandal-maker not go beyond sandals', or, rendered more freely, 'a shoemaker should not pronounce judgments on the matters other than those involving shoes'. The word was invented at the time when most educated people could be presumed to be familiar with such Latin proverbs and so readily 'get' the allusion. Apart from the proverb, it would be very puzzling how this word ('beyond sandals') could have this meaning.

Comment: @jsw29 check those links l have provided. Specifically thar of Cambridge and oxford. This word has a definite meaning now. Again, you are referring to etymological meaning.

Answer (score 1):

As in:

> I can't help but question his **brazen** statements.

**brazen**  [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/brazen)

> unrestrained by convention or propriety

Answer (score 0):

They are **opinionated**:

> firmly or unduly adhering to one's own opinion or to preconceived notions
>   <sub>[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opinionated)</sub>

An opinion doesn't have to be factual in the least (although sometimes it is).

Answer (score 0):

I can't stand his *self-righteous* statements. His *rant  and tirade* are too familiar.

Answer (score 0):

A term denoting precisely such a person, that would be readily understood by most English speakers, is ***know-it-all***. In British English, its variant ***know-all*** is also available. The term is inherently ironic: it means that the person does not, in fact, know very much, let alone 'all', but merely behaves *as if* he does.

The term *ultracrepidarian*, proposed in another answer, has roughly the same denotation, but is probably known to less than 1% of educated English speakers. The choice between the two thus depends on whether one is trying to impress the audience by the richness of one's vocabulary or merely move the communication along smoothly; for the latter purpose *know-it-all* is preferable.

Answer (score -1):

The examples are of someone who speaks "**authoritatively**", but not necessarily accurately or knowledgeably.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/authoritatively

Answer (score -1):

Since you are willing to accept a noun, I think you could use **pundit** or **punditry** here.

> I  question his statements, despite his punditry.
>
> I  question his statements, he is merely a pundit.
>
> I question his statements, he is by reputation a mere pundit.

It need not mean "expert". You need only act like an expert to be a pundit.

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pundit):  "a person who gives opinions in an authoritative manner usually through the mass media"

Compare: [Pundit: From a wise person to an opinionated person](https://www.merriam-webster.com/news-trend-watch/pundit-2016-02-24).

Comment: Sorry to DV, but pundit or pandit don't pretend to be an expert, but they are really an expert. EOLD https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pundit

Comment: @ubi hatt: Your understanding of the word **pundit** may be colored by its origin. The word **pundit** can have negative connotations in contemporary English (at least contemporary American English) where the word is often used as if it were surrounded by "scare-quotes". That is not to say that there are not real experts, but when someone is called a pundit here it does not necessarily mean that the speaker thinks they are an expert.  Many pundits are simply spin-meisters.

Comment: See https://www.merriam-webster.com/news-trend-watch/pundit-2016-02-24

Comment: Well M-W doesn't say anything about "being pretentious". It simply says, a person who presents his/her opinion. That does not qualify "pudit" to be expert without knowledge.

Comment: See the link I added to the answer.

Comment: **mass media** is the keyword here. Also, this meaning is very contemporary.

Comment: That it's a trending contemporary meaning is no reason to downvote the answer. And by "mass media" M-W aren't talking about crowd-sourced wiki articles only but about major national network news outlets.

Comment: It is specifically targeted to a person who presents his/her view on **mass media.** So, we can't generalize the meaning.

Comment: Secondly, a word can't be antonym to itself. You can't have pundit as **an expert** and at the same time **a person who pretends to be an expert.** Oxford dictionary still sticks to the original meaning.

Comment: Well, I would call you a pundit.

Comment: No need to get personal. I won't call you pundit, but an opinionated person. You can't give a preferential treatment to a word as you may please. Have a great day!

Comment: So you do accept the other meaning?

Comment: And words can have opposite meanings; such words are polysemous and they're sometimes called "Janus words".  **pundit** is on its way to becoming one.

Comment: I am aware of the enantiosemy or antilogy. But, pundit which you advocate to be someone **expert without knowledge** is wrong. The meaning  given in your link has a connotation of someone **who forecasted something, but turned out to be something else.** Also, it is used in a very narrow sense. It is specifically targeted to News TV personalities. Sorry, again I have to disagree!

Comment: @ubi hatt:  The word is  becoming double-edged in American English.

Comment: @ubi hatt: And the word **pundit** is rarely used in American English except to refer to the so-called "talking heads" on news outlets. It is often used derisively.

Comment: or more correctly **political pundits.**